# Getting list of data source filters from Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I've been using TableauServerClient to get the list of workbooks and users on Tableau Server.

I want to get a list of all the workbooks which use a specific field as a data source filter but I can't see how/if this is possible, any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the metadata API, you can list all data sources with data source filters with this:

```
query ListDataSourceFilters($first: Int = 1000, $after: String) {
  datasourceFiltersConnection (first: $first, after: $after) {
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
    nodes {
      field{
        name
      }
      datasource {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand you are looking for a specific field, but this should get you started.